# How to use f.select for static hash value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

How can we use f.select tag for collection of static hash values

```
class ReceiptPrinter
         RECEIPT_PRINTER_TYPES ={
            0=> "Normal",
            1=> "Dot Matrix",
            2=> "Thermal",
          }

        def initialize(options={})
                @receipt_printer_type=options[:receipt_printer_type] || DEFAULT_VALUES[:ReceiptPrinterType]
                @receipt_printer_header_height=options[:receipt_printer_header_height]|| DEFAULT_VALUES[:ReceiptPrinterHeaderHeight]
                @receipt_printer_header_type=options[:receipt_printer_header_type]|| DEFAULT_VALUES[:ReceiptPrinterHeaderType]
                @receipt_printer_template=options[:receipt_printer_template]|| DEFAULT_VALUES[:ReceiptPrinterTemplate]
                # define_methods()
        end
 end
```

In my view page i used select option

```
<% form_for @receipt_printer, :url => { :action => "fees_receipt_settings" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.select("receipt_printer_template", @settings.map{| item| [item[0],item[1].to_i]},{},{:onchange => "set_template(this.value)"} ) %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting error wrong number of arguments

Comment: What is the content of `@settings`?

Answer (score 0):

***ANSWER***.

Since `@settings` is just a simple hash, you don't have to use `map`. The `select` form helper should look like:

```
<%= f.select :receipt_printer_template, @settings, {}, {onchange: "set_template(this.value)"} %>
```

***SUGGESTED REFACTOR***

If you are adamant on using `map`, I would suggest to refactor the code a little to prevent your view from being flooded with app logic, something like:

```
# app/helpers/receipt_helper.rb
def settings_for_select
  @settings.map{ |item| [item[0],item[1].to_i] }
end

# your form view
<%= f.select :receipt_printer_template, settings_for_select, {}, {onchange: "set_template(this.value)"} %>
```

Should help a little already, also notice the use of the `new` hash syntax, it provides a cleaner API to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried with code you suggested but am getting empty data in my view page

Comment: Please provide the contents of `@settings`

Comment: @settings = ReceiptPrinter::RECEIPT_PRINTER_TYPES

Comment: If this still doesn't work, there is another problem in your view/controller. Please paste the full controller code in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can try with rails's `options_for_select`,

```
<%= f.select :receipt_printer_template",options_for_select(@settings.map{ |item| [item[0], item[1]],{},{:onchange => "set_template(this.value)"} ) %>
```

[Here is the reference](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

Comment: Thanks for guidance but still am having the same problem

Comment: please check if @settings in nil.